# Sensibility analysis for a discrete output data

Tags: machine-learning, databases

I have a dataset with 1055 samples and 168 features. I want to remove some features in order to train a model on my dataset. The model should output a binary field (either 0 or 1 that is known). Some features are fake, since some of them have been generated randomly and added to the dataset . I want to only keep the relevant features for my training.

I think sensitivity analysis can help with that but I dont know if those algorithms work with discrete output.

**What are the sensitivity analysis or data analysis algorithms that can help studying my dataset?**

I would like some literature alongside some advises.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to define what is "sensibility analysis".  What solutions have you considered so far?  Have you looked at feature selection algorithms?

Comment: You still haven't defined what is "sensibitility analysis".  Also you haven't defined what you mean by a function being "fake".  Therefore I can't tell what you are asking.

Comment: Here is a [link for sensibility analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis). Some "features" not "function" are fake.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the link to your post.  Please correct the spelling of sensitivity.  Please [edit] the post to explain what you mean by "fake".